# New font tags needed such as Garamond?

Tags: discussion, fonts

I wonder what the community thinks about font `tags` such as [minion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minion), [times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/times) that already exist on this page.

This is description of the [minion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minion) tag:

> *Minion* is about how to use the Adobe Minion (Pro) font with LaTeX.
>
> A complete set-up for text and maths fonts based on Minion Pro for
>   (pdf)LaTeX is offered by the MinionPro project or FontPro (the latter
>   supporting newer font versions and fixing some minor bugs). With
>   XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, Minion Pro can be used with the help of the
>   fontspec package.

and this of the [times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/times) tag:

> *Times*
>
> For questions specific to newtx, use the newtx tag. For
>   question concerning the commercial MTPro2 math font, use mtpro. A good
>   starting point is How do I make my document use the Times font, both
>   for the text and the math?.

If these `tags` are regarded as good practice, I would propose other font specific `tags` of frequent used fonts such as *Garamond*, *Myriad*, *CharterBT*, *Helvetica*. But I am not sure, if this really a good idea since there is myriad of possible font tags.

Comment: I believe the need for such font tags arises when people have problems with these fonts or when these fonts are heavily required by the people. We also have a [{libertine}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libertine?sort=votes&pageSize=4) tag (not only) because we had problems with it or want to use it often (even for mathematics). I think we also had a few “How do I make my document use Helvetica for everything?”

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel So you are in favor of creating these tags? The search for Garamond, Helvetica already returns 200+ results in comparison with 50 for pdfx that already has its own tag.

Comment: A Garamond tag would be especially appealing given that getting any kind of Garamond font working in PDF LaTeX on MikTeX is a real nightmare.

Answer (score 10):

It seems I’m only able to post answers and not comments, sorry about that.

When using derivatives such as XeTeX or LuaTeX, specific font tags can be very useful since the OpenType (or other) font features may vary from font to font.

For instance, questions such as “How do I get real superior text in font *α*?” or “Contextual alternates in font *β*” would be easier to locate/filter with appropriate tags.

I would suggest that the tags are created as they are found necessary, since there are lots of fonts out in the wild.

On the other hand, the original question could also be asked as how specific fonts should be tagged. For instance the proposed `garamond` tag, should it refer to all Garamonds? There is Adobe Garamond Pro, EB Garamond, ITC Garamond and many, many others. Most of them having their own feature sets and specific solutions when it comes to questions such as those I asked above.

I’m rather new around here and haven’t yet had the time to explore the tag system fully, so I’m just raising this aspect to those more used to this site and/or more knowledgeable.

Comment: For font problems like why is symbol x not working specific font tags seem to be most helpful. But I guess for minion more than 99% of the users on this site use the Adobe version, so there is no need to create two tags.